# printf giving wrong output

Tags: c, macros, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define square(x) x*x

    void main()
    {
        int i;
        i = 8 / square(4);
        printf("%d %d", i, 8/square(4));
    }
```

Gives output : 8 8

but if I write below code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define square(x) x*x

    void main()
    {
        float i;
        i = 8 / square(4);
        printf("%f %f", i, 8/square(4));
    }
```

Gives Output : 8.000000 0.000000

Why like that??? please explain

Comment: Use floating point literal if you have specified `%f`. `8.0f/square(4.0f)`.

Comment: ALWAYS try to use macros with necessary brackets to make life easier!

Comment: `int main()`... Operator precedence... Wrong format specifier... **Did you even bother reading a basic C tutorial?**

Comment: Preprosessor macros are not the same as functions. They do a *textual* replacement. Understanding what that means is vitally important before you write or use a macro.

Answer (score 2):

The problems are not just with the format specifier but also the way you have defined your macro. It should be:

```
#define square(x) ((x)*(x))
```

**Also macros are not type safe**. Now if you cast your results you will see what is happening, since the square of 4 is 16 and 8/16 is 0.5 which gets truncated to `int` hence becomes 0. For proper values this is how you should typecast:

```
printf("%d %d", (int)i, (int)(8/square(4)));
printf("\n%f %f", (float)i, (float)8/((float)square(4)));
```

[Sample Output](http://ideone.com/QBJj2z):

```
0 0
0.000000 0.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all correct this:

```
#define square(x) x*x
```

to

```
#define square(x) ((x)*(x))
```

for correct results after macro replacement.

Now, in your first program, as others explained you are using wrong format specifier `%f` to print an integer (`8/(square(4)` will evaluate to an integer), which is undefined behavior.

In second program, `8/square(4)` is type promoted to `float` as you are storing the result in `float i`. Therefore, you get `8.000000` on first printing. On second printing, result is wrong due to same reason as above.

Comment: I see no evidence of the first program ever having used `%f` as a format specifier.  If it had, you analysis would be accurate, though.

Answer (score 0):

The first is easy to understand so I focus on the second only. You use %f for the second parameter which requires a float number while C compiler take 8/square(4) as integer. This mismatch corrupt your result.

Answer (score 0):

`8/square(4)` results to an `int` and trying to print an integer using `%f` is [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So there is no use of debugging the value you got in second case.

If you are using gcc compiler then command `cc -E filename.c` may clarify your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you given float as datatype in second program.

8/square(4) will give an integer result, and hence your output becomes wrong. you used %f to print an integer.

That is so simple...

Answer (score 0):

because %f means the type of number is double and default precision